# PHP JSON PUT request 400 Error

Tags: php, json, httprequest, http-status-code-400

I am attempting to use the `PUT` http method using php.

I have created a php array with the information I want to replace the old with:

`$data = array('Customer Name' => 'Sample Name', 'Delivery Address'=>'Sample Address', 'Contact Phone Number'=>'555 - 555 - 5555');`

I then used `json_encode` to format this as a json: 
`$json_data = json_encode($data);`

I put this using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
```

I am  currently getting a 400 error.

What is wrong  with the data I am trying to input?

I know that I'm connecting to the server, but there must be something wrong with the syntax if I'm getting a 400 error.

Comment: Did you check Content-type header ? Did you try using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($json_data)); ?